# Show value in SQL chunk of R value

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

According to [the docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html#sql) I can use (simple) R expressions in RMarkdown's SQL chunks like this:

````
```{r}
subjects = 10
```

```{sql, connection=db}
SELECT * FROM trials WHERE subjects >= ?subjects
```
````

However, in the rendered document I would like to see the actual value of `subjects`, but it shows literally as typed, i.e.

```sql
SELECT * FROM trials WHERE subjects >= ?subjects
```

Any idea how I can substitute `?subjects` in the SQL chunk with the real value, i.e. I would like to see

```sql
SELECT * FROM trials WHERE subjects >= 10
```

in my rendered output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [knitr version 1.16](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-knitr-version-116), you can use option `sql.show_interpolated = TRUE` to opt-in this behavior. It has been added in this [PR](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/1357).

See this example from existing issues on this :

- https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2131

````markdown
---
title: "Get SQL with evaluated variables from SQL chunks"
output: html_document
---
  
In order to provide a reproducible example, we use dplyr and dbplyr with `tbl_memdb` to load a table into a memory db.

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
iris_db <- tbl_memdb(iris)
# we isolate the connection object 
con <- src_memdb()$con
species <- "setosa"
```

We check that it works with SQL chunk to filter data into an R object

```{sql, connection=con, output.var="iris_subset", sql.show_interpolated = TRUE}
SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = ?species
```

```{r}
head(iris_subset)
```
````

You'll see the following where `?species` has been replaced
[image: screenshot of HTML produced by Rmd file which uses knitr and the SQL interpolation opt-in]

Comment: Nice, thanks. As always when you have a problem as simple as that chances ae very hight that somebody had it too already ;)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround which I could think of, is to do the interpolation myself:

````
```{r}
subjects <- 10
sql <- glue_sql("SELECT * FROM trials WHERE subjects >= {subjects}", .con = db)
```

```{sql, connection=db, code = sql}
```
````

But I'd prefer a solution out of the box if there is any?